# How to install on Windows Server 2008, an application that is not natively supported, but not use compatibility mode?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, windows-vista

I have an application to install on Windows Server 2008, which is not natively supported by the installer. The application installer permits installation on Windows Vista(or XP, or 7). I do not want to use compatibility mode; even if I did it doesn't work.

So, how can I spoof the installer to believe it is Windows Vista(or XP, or 7) so that it can proceed with the installation?

Notes: This is an experimental machine, so I am not concerned about stability of the host or the application.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a self extracting archive file, you can try unpacking it and running the MSI by itself.  This might bypass the OS check of the installer.  I've had to do that with a product before.

Comment: @Holocryptic Thanks for the recommendation. I attempted what you have outlined, but the installer is smart enough to find out it is not a supported target OS.